# Kibana: To get all _types by using _index

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I want to search on an index and get all index types under that index.I want to create a terms panel/table for it.It works at index_type level but not at index level.

I'am unable to search by index as well.I used the filter- "_index":"name_of_index", it returned no results but "_type":"name_of_index_type" works fine for searching on type. It returned the expected result. I used the filter- "_index":"name_of_index", it returned no results but "_type":"name_of_index_type" works fine for searching on type. It returned the expected result.

Can it be done using Kibana?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is disabled by default. You can enable it by adding `"_index" : { "enabled" : true }` to your mapping.

Source: [Issue on github](https://github.com/elasticsearch/kibana/issues/1453)